# What is the easiest way to delete all slack messages in the #General channel?

Tags: slack, slack-commands

There seems to be no way to do this, anyone has an idea? There also seems to be some chrome plugins that offer solutions, although I tried a few and none worked, and some methods I've seen on medium are outdated with slack's updates to the application process.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Slack clean all messages (~8K) in a channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32824336/slack-clean-all-messages-8k-in-a-channel)

Comment: @flaxel One can no longer generate legacy tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Note: It's not possible to bulk delete messages. Owners and admins can delete a channel to remove all its messages. Owners on paid subscriptions can also set a retention policy to automatically delete messages after a certain amount of time.

https://slack.com/intl/en-au/help/articles/202395258-Edit-or-delete-messages